# PackageAware Print Driver using Powershell on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, powershell

Does anyone know a way to find out whether a Print Driver is Package aware or not using Powershell for Windows 2008.

I wasn't able to find that info on Win32_PrinterDriver Class but in Print management when we select Drivers tab it has that info. Any way to get it via Powershell?

Comment: Do you have any example code you have tried?

Comment: Actually I am not able to find any location where that information is kept on the Windows Servers. I checked all printer related classes and it doesn't have that. So I am clueless where to look further.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the print drivers that are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, Get-PrintDriver will bring back all the info for your printers. Select Name, IsPackageAware will display the Name of the printer and Bool for if PackageAware

```
Get-PrinterDriver | select Name,IsPackageAware
```

since you said you were working on 2008....I created this.

```
$Answer = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Printers = gwmi win32_printerDriver | select Name,DriverPath
foreach($info in (gwmi win32_printerDriver | select Name,DriverPath)){
    $Path = $info.DriverPath | select-string -Pattern "(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)" | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Get-ChildItem -Filter *.inf
    $answer.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $info.Name
        Path = $Path.FullName
        IsPackageAware = $Path | Get-Content | select-string "PackageAware"
    })
}
$Answer | select name,IsPackageAware
```

It reads the INF files and looks for PackageAware keyword

Comment: Thanks a lot. As far as I know Get-PrintDriver is for Windows 2012 and above (Powershell versions). I need this for Windows 2008. This won't work on Windows 2008. So I basically need the underlying Windows class that this command accesses so that I can use to find PackageAware Print Driver for Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: WOW. JUST WOW. You went through so much trouble. Thanks a lot. It does not work but that is due to Driverpath being a DLL file and not an inf file. So it doesnt output anything. I am looking for a way to find out the inf file so that I can use this. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Got Get-PrinterDriver -ComputerName ServerName| select Name,IsPackageAware working from a Windows 10 Desktop. The Windows 2008 code still doesn't work cause it is unable to pick the inf file. But my work is done so thanks a lot!

Also I suggest you edit the answer to include that.